# What does the columns of the output of ls -la signify?

Tags: linux, ls

When I enter the command:

```
$ ls -la some_directory
```

It gives the output:

```
drwx------. 5 user1 user1 1418 Mar 7 11:17 some_directory
```

What does the dot behind `drwx------` signify?
What does the 5 before `user1` signify?